# Copying a directory in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm successfully able to copy the directory, but it effects the imports of other components.

For example:

```
+ core
  + components
  + views
    + index.js
+ site
  + pages
```

Inside `index.js` i'm importing a file from the components folder `import AdminLayout from '../components/admin/AdminLayout';`

But since I'm copying the file from the `core > views` directory to the `site > pages` directory.

I think I need to create a symlink, but there might be a better way.

This is the block of code that's copying the directory on every startup:

```
  import { ncp } from 'ncp';

  console.log('Copying files...');
  ncp(srcPath, destPath, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Copying files complete.');
  });
```

Comment: `but there might be a better way.`  Indeed, don't copy in the first place..

Comment: Can you give us some more context? It's obvious that moving files will break relative paths (like your `import`s) but why are you copying them if you propose making a symlink anyway?

Comment: @msanford next.js builds the 'page' folder. would creating a symlink between both directories suffice?